# InDesign Paragraph Styles, Object Styles & GREP

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep, character-styles, object-styles

New to the forum, so apologies if this has possible been covered before.

I work in catalogue creation and we've recently transferred over to InDesign
I'm trying to recreate our price lozenges in InDesign and I can only get so far.

What I need to achieve is this:
[image: Lozenge]

Note: I have successfully recreated this using one text frame, a paragraph style and a lengthy amount of GREP Styles.

What I've recreated:
[image]

I am really struggling with the fact that we “need” (my boss needs) the 'each' part of the lozenge to sit on the right-hand side of the lozenge (where it sits in the first screenshot), but for the life of me, I can not find a way to do this without using an Anchored object.

Unfortunately, we're using a CMS and it's quite important that the price imports in one text frame, otherwise the CMS can not export our prices…

If anyone has ANY suggestions, I would REALLY REALLY appreciate it

Comment: How did you define the first and last row to be smaller and the baseline of ".50" to be higher? Is the point of this to be more or less automatic?

Comment: Yes it is going to be automatic. I have used character styles and GREP to apply certain styles to certain parts of the text, essentially superscripting the £ and .00 of the lozenge, and then i have used another character style on the "each" part and shifted the baseline

Comment: after working on this some more, i have managed to get the "each" baseline to the right level, i just need it to shift to the right to be underneath the pence part of our lozenge, but without using characters or invisible characters, as this REALLY screws with our CMS

Comment: The only automatic / non-destructive method that comes to mind is that you could align it all to the right. The other one would be that if you used grep with find/replace,  to replace spaces with line breaks, you could then style them just like you are doing now, but align the "each" to the right separately from the others. Whether or not that would make any sense, depends on the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## Grep Styles

[image: GREP]

- **LIGHTTEXT**: Smaller text size and light style to all the letters `[\l\u]`
- **SUPERSCRIPT**: to `£` and `|` every number after a dot included `\.\d+`
- **NEGATIVETRACKING**: to any number followed by a space `\d\s` (-600 in this example)